# How many records does SNSEvent Object's getRecords() return?

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-java-sdk

How many records will be returned and how does it actually work?

```
public String handleRequest(SNSEvent snsEvent, Context context) {
        List<SNSRecord> records = snsEvent.getRecords();
        System.out.println("Size "+ records.size());
        return "success";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [the docs](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs):

> **Q: Will a notification contain more than one message?**
>
> No, all notification messages will contain a single published message.